# How to fix single quotes in parameterised mySQL query causing this issue?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, prepared-statement, sql-injection

```
  const {tableName,recordId,idName}= req.query;
  const arrayParam=[tableName,idName,recordId];
  let sqlstmt="UPDATE ? SET status = 'deleted' WHERE ? = ?"
    db.query(sqlstmt,arrayParam,(err,result) => {
    if(err){console.log('Error occured while fetching user information',err)
            res.send(err)
              }
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Error:

> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''trainingRecords' SET `status` = 'deleted' WHERE 'recordId' = '10000107'' at line 1",
> sqlState: '42000',
> index: 0,
> sql: "UPDATE 'trainingRecords' SET `status` = 'deleted' WHERE 'recordId' = '10000107'"

In the above snippet, from my understanding, it's the " ' " (single quotes added in the parameterization) that is causing the issue. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You cannot prepare a query with the table name as a parameter. The query compilers cannot compile a query without a table name (that goes for column names as well)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use prepared statements to inject table names or fields that you are using to filter or update. Try using this query.

```
UPDATE trainingRecords SET status = 'deleted' WHERE recordId = ?
```

Comment: I'm attempting to reuse the db query to update in different tables in different scenarios. Whats the best way for this?

Comment: a. Use different queries. b. If you are sure that you won't. receive an SQL injection in these fields, you can just interpolate them using template strings of JS. Please mark this as answer it that hepled.